# Join Multiple Tables MongoDB and returned merged result

Tags: mongodb, nosql, mongodb-query

I have two collections one is user and other is address.
User document has list which contains the publicId of addresses.

I am writing an API to fetch users. How can I return the merged result of user and addresses documents?

User :

```
{    
    "_id" : ObjectId("5684f3c454b1fd6926c324fd"),
    "email" : "user@example.com",
    "userId" : "userId",
    "addresses" : ["A1234","A5678"]
}
```

Address :

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("56d82612b63f1c31cf906004"),
    "publicId" : "A1234"
    "addressLine1" : "AD1",
    "addressLine2" : "AD1",
    "pin" : "001"
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("56d82612b63f1c31cf906005"),
    "publicId" : "A5678"
    "addressLine1" : "AD2",
    "addressLine2" : "AD2",
    "pin" : "002"
}
```

What I am trying to achieve is following

```
{
 "_id" : ObjectId("5684f3c454b1fd6926c324fd"),
 "email" : "user@example.com",
 "userId" : "userId",
 "addresses" : [
  {
   "publicId" : "A1234"
   "addressLine1" : "AD1",
   "addressLine2" : "AD1",
   "pin" : "001"
  },
  {
   "publicId" : "A5678"
   "addressLine1" : "AD2",
   "addressLine2" : "AD2",
   "pin" : "002"
  }
 ]
}
```

how can I achieve this using aggregate query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it working. Following is the aggregate query I used.

```
db.user.aggregate([
   {
      $unwind: "$addresses"
   },
   {
      $lookup:
         {
            from: "address",
            localField: "addresses",
            foreignField: "publicId",
            as: "addresses"
        }
   },
   {
      $match: { 
          "userId":"userId",
          "addresses": { $ne: [] }
          }
   }
])
```

Answer (score 1):

for that you can use [$lookup stage](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/) from aggregation framework:

```
db.user.aggregate([ 
      {$lookup: 
        {
          from : 'addresses', 
          localField: 'Addresses', 
          foreignField: 'publicId', 
          as: 'Addresses'
        }
      }, 
      {$project: {'Addresses._id': 0} }  
]).pretty()
```

for using $lookup (similar to left outer join) you need to use MongoDB version 3.2 or above.

Comment: This is not working. I needed $unwind also since I had array of address Id. I have added the query in my answer that is working. Thanks

Comment: @Ganesh, strange, it works for me even without $unwind. I use mongodb 3.4. I also saw from doc: "If your localField is an array, you’ll need to add an $unwind stage to your pipeline. See the example on this page."

Comment: I tried without unwind it didn't give me any results.